# Selecting rows that have two values in related table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two these two tables:

```
ID   Name           ID   AuthorID   Title
---------           ---------------------
1    John           1    1          Blue
2    Jack           2    1          Yellow
3    Joe            3    2          Blue
                    4    3          Blue
```

How do I select the author that has both books named `Blue` and `Yellow`. I know I can query for authors where book `IN ('Blue', 'Yellow')` but I'm having a hard time grouping (and requiring) both books in the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling first table `AUTHORS` and second table `AUTHOR_TITLE`, use count distinct along with your condition of `IN`.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME 
FROM
AUTHORS A
INNER JOIN
AUTHOR_TITLE B
ON A.ID = B.AUTHORID
AND B.TITLE IN ('BLUE','YELLOW')
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.TITLE) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select authorid
from table2
where title in ('Blue', 'Yellow')
group by authoid
having count(distinct title) = 2;
```

You can use an additional `join` to bring in the author name.